# [iOS]UITableView using auto layout, how to scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview

When my UITableView using auto layout, how to scroll to bottom?
The ContentOffsite is

```
   po self.tableView.contentOffset
   (x = 0, y = 0)
   (x = 0, y = 0)
```

The ContentSize is

```
   po self.tableView.contentSize
   (width = 414, height = 757)
   (width = 414, height = 757)
```

In fact, the ContentOffset is

```
   po self.tableView.contentOffset
   (x = 0, y = 1767.6666666666667)
   (x = 0, y = 1767.6666666666667)
```

The ContentSize is

```
   po self.tableView.contentSize
   (width = 414, height = 2291.3333358764648)
   (width = 414, height = 2291.3333358764648)
```

Comment: Scrolling to the bottom of a table is not anything to do with auto layout. They are completely independent systems. What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: [self.tableView reloadData];
        
        // TODO:Scroll to bottom
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.resultsArray.count inSection:0];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

Comment: The cell at row `self.resultsArray.count` shouldn't exist if you have `self.resultsArray.count` total cells. Try `tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1`.

Comment: @Fogmeister  it couldn't scroll right place